# Unable to complete tasks after calling ksession.dispose in jBpm 5.3

Tags: jbpm

> Hi,
>
> I am unable to complete a task after disposing a knowledge sesion which created the owning process >of the task.I am using jBPM 5.3 version.Please find below the stacktrace.
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal method call. This session was previously disposed.
>
> ```
>       org.drools.reteoo.DisposedReteooWorkingMemory.
>                                      getWorkItemManager(DisposedReteooWorkingMemory.java:386)
>
>       org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.
>                                      getWorkItemManager(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:311)
>
>      org.drools.command.runtime.process.CompleteWorkItemCommand.
>                                      execute(CompleteWorkItemCommand.java:69)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

That is because after you dispose() a ksession you can't use it anymore. If you still have pending tasks you have 2 options:

1. Do not dispose the session until all its tasks have been completed (or no more process instances are running inside it).
2. If you have disposed the session, and you are using persistent sessions, you can reload it from the database using JPAKnowledgeService class BEFORE completing the task.

When a task is completed in jBPM5 the session that created the task MUST be active (must be in memory) and available (not disposed).

Best Regards,

Comment: Thanks Esteban for your suggestion.I tried option 2 and it worked.